# looping to print out - java

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to print out all the elements in the linked list. however, i am unable to print out the complete list of item.

```
public void display()
    {
            int count =0;
            if (head == null)
            {
                    System.out.println("List is empty");
            }
            else {
                    ListNode temp = head;
                    while (temp.getNext() != null)
                    {
                            System.out.println(temp.getElement() +" ");
                            count ++;
                            temp = temp.getNext();

                    }
            System.out.println("Total element: "+count);
            }
    }
```

// methods used

```
public ListNode getNext()
    {
            return this.next;
    }

    /*get the element of Listnode*/

    public int getElement()
    {
            return this.element;
    }
```

please advise which part is wrong.

Comment: Are you using Java's built-in lists? and if you are not, is there a reason for this?

Comment: comment out this statement and try

    temp = temp.getNext()

Comment: Please post a complete (but short) program to demonstrate the problem, we've all had to guess what listNode.next is, and how its set up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're omitting the last element of the linked list (as it has no next element).
The `while` condition should be like this:

```
  while (temp != null)
```

Comment: you're assuming either getElement or getNext actually advance through the list (I also made this assumption), they do not

Comment: @JanHruby You're right, that is really horrible, its a long chain each holding a reference to the next one.

Comment: @Richard Tingle: yep, seems strange to me too, smells like homework :)

Comment: Nothing's horrible about linked lists, it's a simple and flexible data structure, fast for inserting and traversal (also see java.util.LinkedList). Looks like student's homework to me too, knowing how data structures are made is important basic knowledge.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Answer (score 1):

As many answers have correctly said your while loop is missing out the final entry because it exits the loop when the **next** entry is null, thereby not calling `.getElement()` on the final entry in the list. This all assumes that your ListNodes are set up correctly.

#### Use an iterator instead

All of this seems to be replicating the behaviour of an iterator, consider using one instead, an example of one is as follows;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

```
public class Arraylist{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Collection<String> al=new ArrayList<String> ();
        al.add("one");
        al.add("two");
        al.add("three");
        
        Iterator<String> iterator=al.iterator();
        
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            System.err.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Why twice ? getNext only returns the reference to the next node

Comment: @giorashc I must admit I'm assuming some sane implimentation that is unshown. Otherwise it just doesn't work at all and never could

Comment: but he explicitly posted getNext implementation so calling it twice or even more will not advance to the next node.

Comment: @giorashc You are unquestionably right, assuming a sane implementation is never wise

Comment: getNext returns next node. The first it is used to see, if there is next node, and the second time it is used to move to next element. I would guess that the problem is in the code where you actually fill in the list, refence to next node may be corrupted somewhere

Comment: the method itself does not, but if the reference in getNext is filled correctly, he advances explicitly on line 'temp = temp.getNext()'

Answer (score 1):

```
while (temp.getNext() != null)
{
    System.out.println(temp.getElement() +" ");
    count ++;
    temp = temp.getNext();
}
```

Is always stoping before it prints the last item. You need to print the item and then stop if it's `next` is null.

Answer (score 1):

change your while loop condition to :

```
while (temp != null)
```

Since you checked the next node existence than if it does not exist than the current node will not be printed which will make you print all elements but the last one